# Remove kth last element from a Singly Linked List in a single pass

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I'm practising Python and I couldn't think of any solution to this problem.
The problem is to remove kth last element from a singly linked list in just one pass and constant space.
I can only think of a solution that requires 2 passes.
Also, in the question, the size of the list was not mentioned, so I'm assuming the size is known apriori.
Can anyone show me a way to do it in a single pass, please?

Comment: please add some code snippets, if you would like the answer to make more sense :)

Comment: I've written the code for the linked list only. Can't figure out the rest of the logic

Comment: If you need help with the code, you would have to share some snippet for someone here to be able to answer following the same conventions as your code.

Comment: That's not necessary now. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the pointer/location of the item before the item to be removed, in a temp variable as you go along.

So there would be one loop, iterating to the end.
There would be a statement that caches (i-k-1)th element in temp.

When this loop ends, temp would have the location of the item to be removed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't this method require the size of the list?

Comment: No. The first loop iterates till the end, and while iterating a temp variable keeps track of the i-kth element. When you reach the end, that is, i becomes equal to n, you would have you n-kth element. clear?

Comment: ah, got it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If the size is known then you want to remove the `s - kth` element.

If it's not the case then I would use two runners, one is k indices ahead of the second one. When your first runner reaches the end of your list, your second runner is exactly pointing to the kth last element.

Answer (score 0):

[From GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nth-node-from-the-end-of-a-linked-list/)

> Method 2 (Use two pointers)
>
> Maintain two pointers – reference pointer
> and main pointer. Initialize both reference and main pointers to head.
> First move reference pointer to n nodes from head. Now move both
> pointers one by one until reference pointer reaches end. Now main
> pointer will point to nth node from the end. Return main pointer.

An implementation in python is available.